# Calling Javascript from a Form using Onsubmit

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, onsubmit

I am newbie in PHP and AJAX, and I am in trouble and don't know how to solve it.
I am creating this page that shows a recordset that resulted from a query.
There are 2 pages: getdata.php and phpajax.php. phpajax.php calls getdata.php via Javascript.

What I have done:

- I manage to make it work by using button "Try it" (using static value)

What I want:

- How to display the data properly using "Submit" button on a single click (ATM the data appears for a couple of seconds after I click Submit twice, then disappears because the page suddenly refreshes) ?
- How to pass the value of SELECT and TEXT into `fshowdata()` using the Submit Button ?
- How to pass the value of SELECT and TEXT into `fshowdata()` using the "Try It" Button ?

Here is the for the phpajax.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

    <html>
   <head>
  <script>

  function fshowdata(str1,date1) {
    //alert("The form was submitted");
    if (str == "") {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
        return;
   } else { 
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML =      xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    //document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = str1 + " " + date1;
    xmlhttp.open("GET","getdata.php?q="+str1+"&"+"t="+date1,true);

    xmlhttp.send();
}
}
</script>

<style>
table {
width: 100%;
border-collapse: collapse;
}

table, td, th {
border: 1px solid black;
padding: 5px;
}

th {text-align: left;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p id="demo">Click the button to change the text in this paragraph.</p>

<?php


$con = mysql_connect('localhost','root','123');
if (!$con) {
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db('mydb')or die('Could not select database');
$sql="SELECT DISTINCT(rides) FROM t_trx ORDER BY rides ";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());



echo "<form onsubmit='"."fshowdata(`some rides`,`a date`)"."' action='".""."'>";
echo "Choose Rides : "." "."<select id='"."rides"."' name='"."rides"."'>";
echo "<option value='"."ALL"."'>ALL</option>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
echo "<option value='".$row["rides"]."'>".$row["rides"]."</option>";
}
mysql_free_result($result);
echo "</select>";
mysql_close($con);

echo "<input id='"."date2"."' type='"."TEXT"."' name = '"."date2"."'>";
echo "<input id='"."button1"."' type='"."SUBMIT"."' value = '"."SUBMIT"."'>";
echo "</form>";


echo "<button onclick='"."fshowdata(`ROLLER COASTER`,`18/07/2015`)"."'>";
echo "Try it";
echo "</button>";

?>
<br>
<div id="txtHint"><b>Data will be shown here...</b></div>

</body>
</html>
```

And for the getdata.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table {
width: 100%;
border-collapse: collapse;
}

table, td, th {
border: 1px solid black;
padding: 5px;
}

th {text-align: left;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<?php
$q = $_GET['q'];
echo $q;
$date_ = $_GET['t'];
echo $date_;
$con = mysql_connect('localhost','root','123');
if (!$con) {
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db('mydb')or die('Could not select database');

$sql="SELECT * FROM t_trx WHERE rides = '".$q."' AND date1 = '".$date_."'     LIMIT 10";
echo $sql;
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());

echo "<table>
<tr>
<th>Rides</th>
<th>Number</th>
<th>Date</th>
</tr>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['Rides'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['Number'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['Date'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
mysql_close($con);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks guys. I appreciate your help...

Comment: your page refreshes because the submit behavior is not intercepted by your js code. So javascript posts the data, but your browser also submits the page as if it were a classic form. you might consider using jQuery, it would simplify things for you. there are tons of examples online on how to make ajax calls with jQuery.

Comment: Thx Hakim. Do u have some samples about it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use below code to skip refresh page

```
onsubmit="return fshowdata(`some rides`,`a date`)"
```

in the fshowdata function, you should return false.

Comment: sorry! you should return false;

Comment: yup. it works.. thx @selvan. How about passing the form value into the fshowdata() ?

Comment: no need to pass. In the fshowdata function, you can get the value. ex:  date2 = document.formname.date2.value;